# How to make element NOT to resize on window resize / resolution change

Tags: css

I have simple login box, which is centered to the middle of page (vertical and horizontaly).

Here you can find DEMO for it:

http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/login.html

Problem is that everytime I resize browser window manually the content of `div` (`#login-logout-box`) is being resized, if someone is trying to view this login form in browser window, which height is lower then `380px`, it should add scrollbars to the page. But atm instead of that box is just cutten off. Means that under low resolution this form is partically shown without ability to scroll :S (tryed several phones - Iphone and Android 2.3)

But again I don't want that `div` to be scrollable but whole page.

I've checked www and stackoverflow for possible answer, but nothing at all, also I'm sorry if question is unclear, I've tryed my best to describe it.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you simply set a fixed size of an element, scroll-bars will automatically appear whenever it overflows the window... isn't that what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes, exactly. But for some reasson it's not happening in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: It's not working in Safari either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should not be working in any browser at all.  As per the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning), *"Boxes with fixed position that are larger than the page area are **clipped**."*

Simply change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;`

```
#login-loguout-box {
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -190px;
    margin-top: -190px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #cacaca;
}​
```

[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/QbUQq/)

[Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QbUQq/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `overflow` setting in css, e.g.

```
overflow-x: auto; /* for horizontal scrolling*/
overflow-y: auto; /* for vertical scrolling */
```

Comment: That adds scrollbars to it, true. But I don't want scrollbars when they are not needed, only want them there when browser resolution is to small to show whole form.